# How to configure the subnets for EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I am currently learning about deploying EKS (via Terraform), and looking to understand how to set up the number of subnets needed, and whether they are public or private. This is a snippet for how my code looks like for EKS:

```
module "eks_cluster" {
  source                    = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version                   = "13.2.1"
  cluster_name              = "${var.project_name}-meow-${var.environment}"
  cluster_version           = "1.18"
  vpc_id                    = module.vpc.vpc_id
  cluster_enabled_log_types = ["api", "audit", "authenticator", "controllerManager", "scheduler"]
  enable_irsa               = true
  subnets                   = [module.vpc.subnet_a_private_id, module.vpc.subnet_b_private_id, module.vpc.subnet_a_public_id]
}
```

To rephrase my question, I am looking to understand:

- How many subnets do I need to deploy EKS to? Should I deploy it on all the subnets in the VPC?
- What difference does it make if I deploy EKS to all public or all private subnets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend having a look at [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network_reqs.html) which explain the role of VPC when you create your EKS cluster. Based on the link, the following are the answers to your questions:

> How many subnets do I need to deploy EKS to? Should I deploy it on all the
> subnets in the VPC?

At **least two subnets** in different availability zones. Using all subnets is a default behavior in AWS console.

> What difference does it make if I deploy EKS to all public or all private subnets?

From [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network_reqs.html) on VPC in EKS:

> **Private-only**: Everything runs in a private subnet and Kubernetes cannot create internet-facing load balancers for your pods.

> **Public-only**: Everything runs in a public subnet, including your nodes.

Also:

> We **recommend a VPC with public and private subnets** so that Kubernetes can create public load balancers in the public subnets that load balance traffic to pods running on nodes that are in private subnets.